# Problems about decoding the data dumped from ARM memory

Tags: memory, arm, decode, objdump

Now I got some content dumped from the memory of an ARM machine. The thing is actually they are ARM instructions, but I don't know how to convert those hex numbers to ARM instructions. What I have now is the "arm-elf-objdump" can read .bin file and disassemble the content in the .bin file. But I just have the texts of hex numbers which is different from the binary file. How can I do this decode?

E.g.

```
  800104:       e3a00000        mov     r0, #0  ; 0x0
  800108:       e59f104c        ldr     r1, [pc, #76]   ; 80015c <_jump_main+0x4>
  80010c:       e59f204c        ldr     r2, [pc, #76]   ; 800160 <_jump_main+0x8>
```

Actually the "e3a00000" means "mov r0, #0". There should be a tool to do this. 
Any one can give me some suggestions?

Comment: You have the instructions, as the next two are load register.  What are you missing?

Comment: This is the analysis result of an existing .bin file. What I have now is a program which can dump content from memory, sometimes I guess the content I get is code, so I need a program to help me analysis the hex numbers from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your text file to a binary file which should be trivial even you have to write a script/application yourself then use objdump to disassemble.

```
objdump -D -b binary -marm <binary_file>
```

However also be careful to instruction encoding, you'll get wildly different results if you select `arm` for `thumb` encoding. See [objdump manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) part about `--disassembler-options=force-thumb`.

Comment: Now convert a text file to a binary file is the problem. I know the command "objdump", actually I use arm-elf-objdump. The problem is for example, the "e3a00000" means "mov  r0, #0", but when I put e3a00000 using fwrite into a binary file, I cannot get the right instruction

Comment: Sorry the link you gave me is not what I want...This kind of translate is not like encoding the words directly using ASCII or something. ARM is RISC, every 8 hex number means an instruction. There is a command I already know to translate the binary file, what I need now is to translate the hex to binary correctly

Answer (score 1):

The tool you're looking for is called a 'disassembler'.  A common one is GNU objdump, as you've found.  I'm not sure if it can handle text input, but you can write a simple program to convert it back to binary if necessary.

Comment: Actually my problem is I don't know how to convert the text to binary correctly. I tried several ways but cannot get the right result...For example, I have a text with content "e3a00000", in ARM, it means "mov r0, #0", when I tried to convert text file contained"e3a00000" to binary file, then use arm-elf-objdump to analyze the binary file, I got wrong output...

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I have finished this task, I will answer my own question so maybe someone can get help from my answer.

My problem is made of two parts:
The first one is that I don't know clearly how "arm-elf-objdump" work. In my case, I use

```
arm-elf-objdump -D -b binary -marm binaryfile.dat
```

This will help to disassemble the ARM code if the binaryfile.dat is correct.

The second problem is how to make binaryfile.dat correct.
For example,

```
800104:       e3a00000        mov     r0, #0  ; 0x0
```

When I dumped hex number e3a00000 from RAM, actually I almost got the instruction. Then I use

```
const uint8_t num=0xe3a00000;
fp = fopen("binaryfile.dat", "wb+");
fwrite(&num, sizeof(const uint8_t), 1, fp);
```

This will write "e3a00000" in the binaryfile.dat which is a binary file(in Linux). Then I used

```
hexer binaryfile.dat
```

to check and found it is correct, then used

```
arm-elf-objdump -D -b binary -marm binaryfile.dat
```

What I got is

```
> arm-elf-objdump -D -b binary -marm binaryfile.dat
binaryfile.dat:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
0:  e3a00000    mov r0, #0  ; 0x0
```

That's all, I am a beginner in this area and thanks for all the people who helped me. If you find some problems, please let me know :)